# Changing a RecyclerView's Layout upon orientation change only works on the first view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my application i have this code to calculate phone size and change `RecyclerView` layout manager to `GridLayoutManager` or `LinearLayoutManager`

```
private void changeFeedsLayout() {
    // Choose between one, two or three elements per row
    if (dpWidth > 720 && getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(
                context, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    } else if (dpWidth > 520) {
        instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(
                context, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    } else {
        instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(
                context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    }
}
```

this code work fine when i attach or commit each fragment to container on `MainActivity` , but it doesn't work when in change phone orientation, for fix this problem i'm using this code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    changeFeedsLayout();
}
```

and unfortunately layoutmanager of `RecyclerView` is `LinearLayoutManager` always and i can't resolve that. after switch on other fragment and back to previous fragment work fine.

**UPDATE**

on change phone orientation this code as:

```
instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(
                    context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
```

don't work on phone change orientation  on `changeFeedsLayout()` method and this method couldn't calculate correctly phone size on change phone orientation

Comment: Test case try to set adapter again to the `RecyclerView` in your `changeFeedsLayout()` method

Comment: @NileshRathod don't work correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may sound strange, but the only valid solution for this case is to put this settings into resources. Android OS picks up resources basing on lots of properties and one of them is smallest width. To separate list from grid:
**values/bools.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_grid">false</bool>
</resources>
```

the other one will be **values-sw520dp/bools.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="is_grid">true</bool>
</resources>
```

For number of columns same logic **values-sw520dp/integers.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="grid_column_count">2</integer>
</resources>
```

And **values-sw720dp/integers.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="grid_column_count">3</integer>
</resources>
```

So in code this will be something like:

```
if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_grid)) {
    instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count));
} else {
    instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
}
```

This should be applied whenever you create your view, no need to handle config change - it's done for you already. Give the OS do its work.

Comment: +1. Note that you must _not_ override `onConfigurationChanged()` when you use this strategy. (In fact, you should basically _never_ override `onConfigurationChanged()` or use `android:configChanges` in your manifest; it's better to work with the OS as Viktor says.)

Answer (score 2):

`GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams` are explained in it's comments:

```
if the orientation is VERTICAL, the width parameter is ignored and

if the orientation is HORIZONTAL, the height parameter is ignored

because child view is expected to fill all of the space given to it.
```

the point is:

that a `LinearLayoutManager` will always have 1 single column;

while a `GridLayoutManager` "may" have 1 (or more) column(s).

Comment: your mean is instead of `LinearLayoutManager` i shoud be use `GridLayoutManager` such as `instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)`?

Comment: @DolDurma use `GridLayoutManager` and set 1 column, then you don't have to switch the layout managers... which should result in a problem less to care about.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to handle the change in orientation and work accordingly, I've done the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Log.i("SCREEN DP","Orientation:"+ getResources().getConfiguration().orientation +" Width = "+getWidthDp());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.i("SCREEN DP","Orientation:"+ newConfig.orientation +" Width = "+getWidthDp());
    }

    public float getWidthDp(){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    }
}
```

The logs show :

```
I/SCREEN DP: Orientation:1 Width = 411.42856
I/SCREEN DP: Orientation:2 Width = 683.4286
I/SCREEN DP: Orientation:1 Width = 411.42856
I/SCREEN DP: Orientation:2 Width = 683.4286
```

Don't forget to add `android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"` on the Manifest in order to be able to handle all the orientations.